# Guardar los valores de la tabla

Tags: javascript

Necesito su ayuda, soy nuevo en esto de JavaScript. Mi tabla crea nuevas filas y dentro de ella puedo agregarle los datos, solo que lo que yo quiero es que los campos agregados se "guarden" (por así decirlo) cada vez que le agregue una nueva fila. Al *guardar* me refiero que los campos ya aparezca en la tabla pero que ya no se puedan editar. Este es un código ejemplo que conseguí:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bt_add').click(function() {
    agregar();
  });
  $('#bt_del').click(function() {
    eliminar(id_fila_selected);
  });

  $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
    eliminarTodasFilas();

  });


});
var cont = 0;
var id_fila_selected = [];

function agregar() {
  cont++;
  var fila =

    '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + '" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>&nbsp;</td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="area"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="email"></td></tr>';


  $('#tabla').append(fila);
  reordenar();
}

function seleccionar(id_fila) {
  if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
    $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
  } else {
    $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
  }
  //2702id_fila_selected=id_fila;
  id_fila_selected.push(id_fila);
}

function eliminar(id_fila) {
  /*$('#'+id_fila).remove();
  reordenar();*/
  for (var i = 0; i < id_fila.length; i++) {
    $('#' + id_fila[i]).remove();
  }
  reordenar();
}

function reordenar() {
  var num = 1;
  $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
    num++;
  });
}

function eliminarTodasFilas() {
  $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

}
```

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
}

.selected {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected:hover {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}

.seleccionada {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="content">
  <label> Tabla de Ejemplo </label>
  <br>
  <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</button>
  <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar</button>
  <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar todo</button>

  <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Nº</td>
        <td>NOMBRE</td>
        <td>AREA</td>
        <td>PUESTO</td>
        <td>EMAIL</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el tour para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El id del td no te da el valor de lo que hay en la celda, ese modo de recoger un valor es para inputs de formularios, así no va a funcionar, debes añadir los correspondientes inputs. Si quieres hacerlo sin inputs tendrás que recoger lo que hay dentro del td.

Comment: `<?=$resultado['id']?>` no corresponde a la sintaxis de HTML/CSS/JavaScript. ¿De dónde obtuviste el código?

Comment: Eso lo quite, pero aun no me guarda.

Comment: @ReinosRic Haz clic en el enlace [edit] para actualizar el código de la pregunta. Cabe mencionar que  el fragmento al que me refería en el comentario anterior fue sólo un ejemplo. No está claro a que refieres por guardar; deberías incluir una descripción de los que pretendes lograr con tu código. Mäs detalles en [mcve].

Comment: Ya modifique mi pregunta... ojala y pueda ayudarme

Comment: sigue sin quedar claro a que te refieres con `guardar`

Comment: Que los campos que agregue en las filas se capturen ya dentro de la tabla y no se puedan modificar, osea que sea solo texto

Comment: Acabo de editar tu pregunta poniendo los CDN de jquery, boostrap y tether. Por favor, cuando publiques código que necesite dependencias, coloca de ser posible los CDN para poder tener un código *ejecutable*. Respecto a tu pregunta y, ejecutando el código que tienes, asumo que te refieres por *guardar* al hecho de que, luego de escribir en las cajas de texto, deseas que con un Enter se inserte en la tabla. ¿Estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: Si, es la acción que quiero que haga @GustavoGarcía

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te falta es agregar lo que has escrito en la tabla como texto. Para esto, puedes poner un escuchador para en el evento `keyup` en la última caja de texto, para proceder a guardar lo ingresado en la tabla en cuando se detecte un *Enter*.

**Ejemplo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bt_add').click(function() {
    agregar();
  });
  $('#bt_del').click(function() {
    eliminar(id_fila_selected);
  });

  $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
    eliminarTodasFilas();

  });


});
var cont = 0;
var id_fila_selected = [];

function agregar() {
  cont++;
  var fila =

    '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + '" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>&nbsp;</td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="area"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"></td>' +

    '<td><input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>';


  $('#tabla').append(fila);
  reordenar();
}

/*
 * Esta función agrega lo ingresado a la tabla
 */
function addToTable(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
    const values = [].map.call(inputs, input => input.value);
    const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    [].forEach.call(tds, (td, i) => {
      if (i === 0) { td.textContent = i + 1; }
      else { td.innerHTML = values[i - 1]; }
    });
  }
}

function seleccionar(id_fila) {
  if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
    $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
  } else {
    $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
  }
  //2702id_fila_selected=id_fila;
  id_fila_selected.push(id_fila);
}

function eliminar(id_fila) {
  /*$('#'+id_fila).remove();
  reordenar();*/
  for (var i = 0; i < id_fila.length; i++) {
    $('#' + id_fila[i]).remove();
  }
  reordenar();
}

function reordenar() {
  var num = 1;
  $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
    num++;
  });
}

function eliminarTodasFilas() {
  $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

}
```

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
}

.selected {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected:hover {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}

.seleccionada {
  background-color: #0585C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="content">
  <label> Tabla de Ejemplo </label>
  <br>
  <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</button>
  <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar</button>
  <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar todo</button>

  <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Nº</td>
        <td>NOMBRE</td>
        <td>AREA</td>
        <td>PUESTO</td>
        <td>EMAIL</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono, aun falta algunas cosas que pulirse al programa si tengo otra duda ¿Me podría ayudar?

Comment: Si tienes otra duda, publícala. Si te sirvió mi problema, no olvides marcarla como correcta.